# Thermal radiation in hollow sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conduction

I have been asked to calculate the time taken for a **highly conducting** hollow sphere to cool down from a certain temperature say $\theta_1$ to a temperature $\theta_2$ ($\theta_1, \theta_2 > \theta_s$) where $\theta_s$ is the surrounding temperature. We are given the inner and outer surface area, which implies it has a certain thickness.

My doubt is, will the hollow sphere radiate heat both through the inner and outer surface? If so, will the temperature on both interfaces remain the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to look at this is to imagine a vacuum in the cavity. Heat radiated from one side of the inner surface, is almost immediately reabsorbed on the opposite side of the cavity, so there is an equilibrium inside the cavity and no net loss internally.

Another way of looking at it is that the question is about the time for whole sphere to cool down. If any heat was lost to the interior, that heat is still inside the sphere as a whole and so there is no net loss from the the sphere as a whole. That heat can only escape by conduction through the shell and radiation to the environment outside the shell.

The importance of the thickness of the shell is that the heat capacity of an object is proportional to the volume of the material and you need the shell thickness to calculate the total volume of the shell material and the total amount of heat energy that has to be radiated away.

> I am confused since you mention vacuum, the temperature in a vacuum
> must be zero by definition. –  QuantumQuipster

Re: vacuum temperature. The vacuum of space is considered to non-zero. It is few degrees above absolute zero due the Cosmic Microwave Background Radiation (CMBR). Radiation inside the cavity (from the interior surface) is energy and is counted as part of the temperature of the vacuum. As I mentioned before, any radiation internally is quickly reabsorbed, but there is a finite period between being radiated and reabsorbed and while the radiation is in transit across the cavity, it contributes to the temperature of the cavity vacuum.

Better still. Lets say X Joules of energy is radiated into the cavity every second. In equilibrium the same amount of radiation is reabsorbed by the shell every second. Now disregard the radiation entering the cavity for now. Every second, x amount of joules exits the boundary or effective surface of the cavity. Now temperature of a volume of a material is proportional to the amount of energy that is radiated from the surface of the material per unit time per unit surface area (M). This can be seen from the [Stefan-Boltzman law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law): $$M = \sigma T^4 $$

$$ T = \left( \frac{M}{\sigma} \right) ^{1/4}$$

In our case the vacuum is radiating x joules per second so it has a non zero temperature.

> I have been asked to calculate the time taken for a **highly
> conducting** hollow sphere to cool down from a certain temperature say
> $\theta_1$ to a temperature $\theta_2$ ($\theta_1, \theta_2 >
> > \theta_s$) where $\theta_s$ is the surrounding temperature.

Be aware if $\theta_2 > \theta_s$ the situation will still be dynamic and the internal temperature will be different to the external surface temperature at time 2. This means heat lost by the sphere will not simply be heat capacity of the sphere multiplied by the change in external temperature of the sphere.

> Could you please explain how filling the inside with a specific
> material affects thermal conductivity in a case? Thank you. –
> QuantumQuipster

This can get complicated and you will see why below. The good news is that thermal properties like [conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity_and_resistivity), resistivity, and resistance are analogous analogous to their electrical counterparts and have similar mathematical properties. For example (treating voltage as temperature) thermal resistance in series can simply be added like electrical resistance in series.

The bad news is that resistance is a function of cross sectional area and in the case of heat energy conducting from the centre of a solid sphere to the exterior, the cross sectional area is continually expanding and will involve doing some probably complicated integration calculations. This sub case of the thermal conductivity of a sphere composed of shells of different material deserves its own post, because its not that trivial.

For a vacuum filled cavity, the cavity temperature is pretty much the same as the the interior surface of the shell at any instant and you can pretty much ignore the cavity in your calculations ;-)

Comment: How can heat be reabsorbed from a region of colder temperature (The inside environment) to hotter(The shell)?

Comment: Who says the temperature inside the cavity is colder than the shell? Is that specified in the question? Let's say the cavity contains air. At the start of the experiment it is reasonable to assume the air inside the cavity is in equilibrium with the shell.

Comment: I am confused since you mention vacuum, the temperature in a vacuum must be zero by definition.

Comment: Basically yes. Like I said the shell thickness is important in calculating the thermal capacity of the shell itself. If there is another material such as air or foam filling, you would have to allow for the thermal capacity and thermal conductivity of the internal filling material making the question a bit more complicated.

Comment: Re vacuum temperature: Added a bit to the answer.

Comment: That makes it more clear to me, it seems that I was getting confused with heat transfer by non-radiation methods. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how filling the inside with a specific material affects thermal conductivity in a case? Thank you.

Comment: See new addition to my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,we only account for the outer surface (surface area of the sphere).There are two kinds of heats transfer going on here:

1)**Radiation:**Body emits and absorbs heat to and from the surroundings;in this case it is emiting more heat due to temperature difference with the surroundings.

2)**Conduction:**we can view this hollow sphere as a shell too;a shell with certain thickness.Now,in this layer of shell the molecules will conduct heat from inner layer to outer layer in contact with the surroundings,so there will a temperature difference on both interfaces but very very small(almost negligible so we dont acknowledge it will solving problems.)

I hope you find this useful.